# Backend only accepts plain text, no JSON and only a name not an id

Tags: json, angular, rest, http, glassfish

So I want to send data to the backend in JSON format. The user has to select an option from the datalist and a id and name will be sent to the REST server. When I send the id and name of the selected option from the datalist, it gives me an error message: internal server error 500 and SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

I edited the data to only send the name to the server via mozilla debug options, then it accepts the POST request with a 201 response. When I only send a id it gives the same 500 internal server error response.
Why does it only accept it when I send a name? How can I change it so that the Get request shows a id and a name?

I use Angular 7 for frontend and glassfish REST server for the backend. I hope someone can help me.
I checked the JSON format in a JSON checker and it passed the test. I will provide some photos in the comments to show you what I mean.

Here is an example of what I am trying to send:

```
{"id":3,"name":"Burger King"}
```

What it only accepts:

```
{"name":"Burger King"}
```

FRONTEND

HTML file:

```html
<label for="codes">Choose a restaurant:</label>
    <form
      (ngSubmit)="onOrganize(f)"
      #f="ngForm">
      <input type="text"  list="codes"  [(ngModel)]=codeValue [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (change)="saveCode($event)">
      <datalist id="codes">
        <option *ngFor="let c of codeList" [value]="c.name" >{{c.name}}</option>
      </datalist>
    </form>
```

Typescript file:

```js
export class OrganizeComponent implements OnInit {

  public codeValue: string;

  codeList = [
    { restaurantId: 1, name: 'Mcdonalds' },
    { restaurantId: 2, name: 'Kentucky Fried Chicken' },
    { restaurantId: 3, name: 'Burger King' },
    { restaurantId: 4, name: 'Dominos pizza' },
    { restaurantId: 5, name: 'New York Pizza' }
  ];


  @ViewChild('f') form: NgForm;
  restaurant = {
    restaurantId: 1,
    name: " "
  };
   httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
    })
  };


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public saveCode(e): void {
    let name = e.target.value;
    let list = this.codeList.filter(x => x.name === name)[0];



    this.restaurant.restaurantId =  list.restaurantId;
    this.restaurant.name = list.name;

console.log(list.restaurantId);
console.log(list.name);



    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };

    const data = {
      id: list.restaurantId,
      name: list.name
    };

    console.log(data)
    var yourDataStr = JSON.stringify(data)

    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/aquadine-jee/resources/restaurant',
      JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) , httpOptions)


      .subscribe( // subscribe to observable http.post
        res => {
          console.log("response" + " " + res); // log results otherwise log error
        },
        err => {
          console.log('Error occured');
        }
      );
  }
```

BACKEND

Restaurant file:

```js
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Restaurant.findOne", query = "select m from Restaurant m where m.id = :id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Restaurant.getAll", query = "select m from Restaurant m")
})
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;


//    @NotBlank
    private String naam;


//    @NotBlank
    private String adres;


    private int restaurantId;

    public Restaurant(){

    }


   public Restaurant( int id, int restaurantId, String naam) {
        this.id = id;
        this.restaurantId = restaurantId;
        this.naam = naam;
    }

 @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
        public Response all(){
             List<Restaurant> all = repositoryService.getAllRestaurants();
            return Response
                    .status(200)
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .entity(all)
                    .build();
        }


    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response save(Restaurant restaurant){
        repositoryService.save(restaurant);
        return Response
                .status(201)
                .build();
    }
```

Repository file

```
// Restaurant services
    public List<Restaurant> getAllRestaurants(){

        return entityManager.createNamedQuery("Restaurant.getAll", Restaurant.class).getResultList();

    }

    public Restaurant find(Integer id){

        return entityManager.createNamedQuery("Restaurant.findOne", Restaurant.class).setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();

    }

    public void save(Restaurant restaurant){
        entityManager.persist(restaurant);
    }
    public void update(Restaurant restaurant){
        entityManager.merge(restaurant);
    }
    public void delete(Restaurant restaurant){
        entityManager.remove(restaurant);
    }
```

Comment: Images: [What I am trying to send](https://i.imgur.com/cpt1WdA.png) and [What gets accepted](https://i.imgur.com/RnyBlyX.png)

Comment: look like inside your controller path is incorrect or send the data in correct format from your angular service, Please add your controller here, with entity its not possible to find it out

Answer (score 0):

When you receive using Modal class in the back end, the data that you sent should map to model class. For Eg :

> Backend naming conversion should be same as receiving data

You are sending

```
{"id":3,"name":"Burger King"}
```

So that the model class

**Mapping model class**

```
class Restaurant{
    Integer id; 
    String name; // your variable name is naam, so it won't map

    //Getters and setters
    //constructor -- You should have argument constructor 
}
```

You are sending `name`, but there is a spelling mistake in the model class `naam`